# How to Change the Side By Side Direction in VSCode depending on file type

Tags: html, sql, visual-studio-code

I prefer using vscode on side by side right mode when coding html, js, css, etc... but when I am working with server queries (sql), I prefer side by side down mode.

Is there a way to automatically change the layout direction depending on the file type/extensions that are being used, so I don't have to manually change the setting every time I am coding vs querying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a keybinding like this:

```json
[
  {
    "key": "ctrl+\\",
    "command": "workbench.action.splitEditorDown",
    "when": "editorLangId == sql"
  }
]
```

I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>  as the keybinding, which is usual split command, but you can make that whatever you want.

The above keybinding goes into your `keybindings.json` file, which can be found from the Command Palette as `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`.  That `keybindings.json` file is where your custom keybindings will go.

Comment: Could you provide more detail on this? How/where do I put in the keybinding?

Comment: I added some more info to the answer.  Let me know if that isn't enough.  The general documentation is https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just adding keybindings to split in whatever direction I wanted, so I don't have to worry about automatically splitting based on file types.